# Responsitivity for div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem concerning responsitivity. I want this symbol "=" to hold all the menu when the screen is smaller(let say 1000px). I know I have to use responsitivity but I don't know how.

This is my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
     <title>Tagesmutter Kiel</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #41430e">
 <!--a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="icon" onclick="allLinksInOneDiv()">&#9776;</a-->
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="icon-bar">
       <a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
      </div>


      <div class="dropdown_wohnen">
       <button class="dropbtnWohnen">Wohnen</button>
         <div class="wohnen_content">
            <a href="wohnen.html">Eingenwöhnung</a>
            <a href="konzeption.html">Konzeption</a> 
        </div>
      </div>    

      <div class="dropdown_betreung">
       <button  class="dropbtnBetreung">Betreungskosten</button>
         <div class="betreungskosten_content">
             <a href="betreuungskosten.html">Betreuungskosten</a>
             <a href="freiePlaetze.html">Freie Plätze</a>
             <a href="fotos.html">Bilder</a>
         </div>     
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown_tag">
       <button  class="dropbtnTag">Tagesablauf</button>
         <div class="tag_content">
             <a href="tagesablauf.html">Tagesablauf</a>
             <a href="tageskinder.html">Tageskinder</a>
             <a href="kommentar.html">Gästebuch</a>
         </div>     
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown_kontakt">
        <button  class="dropbtnKontakt">Kontakt</button>
          <div class="kontakt-content">
            <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
            <a href="urlaub.html">Urlaub</a>
            <a href="info.html">Über mich</a>
         </div>
      </div>

</div>

<div class="banner">
  <img class="mySlides" src="../img/img1.jpg" height ="270" style="width:100%" alt="bannerSlide">
  <img class="mySlides" src="../img/img2.jpg" height ="270" style="width:100%" alt="bannerSlide">
  <img class="mySlides" src="../img/img3.jpg" height ="270" style="width:100%" alt="bannerSlide">
</div>

<div class="info">
<h1>Hallo, liebe Eltern! </h1>
 <p style="
 padding-left: 10px"> Sie suchen eine Tagesmutter für Ihr Kind? <br>

 Ich hoffe, dass ich Ihnen mit diesen Seiten einen kleinen Einblick

in meine Arbeit als Tagesmutter ermöglichen kann. &#x263A; </p>

<h5>Tagesmutter Irene</h5>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And now the stylesheet:

```
#menu
{
    background-color: #78409a;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -2%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 68%; 
}


.icon-bar { margin-right: 0.2%;}

.icon-bar a 
{
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 710%;    
}


.active {background-color: #4CAF50;}


.dropdown_whohnen 
{ 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtnWohnen 
{
    background-color: #4CAF50 ;
    color: white;
    padding: 33.25%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}


.wohnen_content 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #d5416e;
    min-width: 13.2%;
    box-shadow: 10px 8px 16px 10px rgba(0,1,1,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.wohnen_content a 
{
    color: black;
    padding: 6% 6%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown_wohnen:hover .wohnen_content {display: block;}
.dropdown_wohnen:hover .dropbtnWohnen {background-color: #3e8e41;}
.wohnen_content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}


.dropdown_betreung 
{    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.3%;
}

.dropbtnBetreung
{
    background-color: #4CAF50 ;
    color: white;
    padding: 24.7%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.betreungskosten_content 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #DAF7A6 ;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 10px 8px 16px 10px rgba(0,1,1,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.betreungskosten_content a 
{
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown_betreung:hover .betreungskosten_content {display: block;}
.dropdown_betreung:hover .dropbtnBetreung {background-color: #3e8e41;}
.betreungskosten_content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.dropdown_tag 
{    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.3%;
}


.dropbtnTag
{
    background-color: #4CAF50 ;
    color: white;
    padding: 29.2%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}


.tag_content 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #78409a ;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 10px 8px 16px 10px rgba(0,1,1,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.tag_content a 
{
    color: black;
    padding: 5% 5%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}


.dropdown_tag:hover .tag_content {display: block;}
.dropdown_tag:hover .dropbtnTag {background-color: #3e8e41;}
.tag_content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}


.dropdown_kontakt
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.3%;

}

.dropbtnKontakt
{
    background-color: #4CAF50 ;
    color: white;
    padding: 34.09%;
    font-size: 100%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.kontakt-content 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #12d3df;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 10px 8px 16px 10px rgba(0,1,1,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.kontakt-content a 
{
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown_kontakt a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
.dropdown_kontakt:hover .kontakt-content {display: block;}
.dropdown_kontakt:hover .dropbtnKontakt {background-color: #3e8e41;}


.banner
{
    height: 270px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 68%;
    background-color: white;
}

.mySlides {display:none;}

.info h1, h5, h3
{
    font-family: 'Tangerine';
    font-size: 78px;
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #aaa
}



.info
{
    background-color:  #a6debb;
    margin-top: -4%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 68%;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 22px 22px 22px #aaa;

}


.info p
{
    padding-left: 10px; 
    font-family: 'Helvetica', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-shadow: 22px 22px 22px #aaa;

}



table
{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}


td, th 
{
    border: 1px solid  #9a1838 ;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #dddddd;
}


#map 
{
    margin-left: 9%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Please, can you help me with this? And I also have a display different depending on the browser ( Firefox vs chrome).

Comment: check the @media proprety https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Thank you for the help but i'm looking how to put all the links in a div block when the window size changes. For plaintext i can do it.

Comment: If your code cannot adapt to mobile design then you would have to make another block with the content you want. Then show/hide based on media query however it is best if you can use the same code for desktop and mobile

Comment: Thank you Huangism that's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question it seems you want to build a mobile navigation menu that opens when clicking the symbol "=".

You need to do the following:

**- HTML:** Add a list within an unordered list, to hold the anchor links. This is the navigation text you will see when it is expanded. Attach an onclick functionality that will be used in below javascript.

**- CSS:** Style your navigation menu.

**- Javascript:** Create a function that reacts on the HTML onclick. This function will expand your navigation menu. Your function should be able to toggle the menu, meaning that same button should be able to open/close the menu.

---

...if your need further assistance please create a code snippet.